# How to transmit data to the Modal? (bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I used the bootstrap's Modal. However, I do not know how to transmit data to the Modal.

As simple Modal:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="view_user" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" 
               data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                  &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
               user information
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>ID：10001</p>
            <p>Bob</p>

         </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

If I open a new page, I can transmit the data like this:

```
 router.get('home',function(req, res){
    res.render('home',{title:'Home', userid: '10001', username:'Bob'});
})
```

;

By this way, I can get the title, userid, username.
How to do this with Modal?

Comment: using jquery you can add these values into the modal body right?

Comment: Can you give me an instance?just a url to a related passage is fine. THX

Comment: I am not familiar with node js.. so I dont think ill be helpful in that area..